# Dont center marker onClick

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have Maps Realisation and when I'm clicking on the marker, I don't want to center marker on the map. How to override this? I've tried to override `setOnMapClickListener`, but it doesn't work:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        googleMap ?: return
        with(googleMap) {
            setOnMapClickListener {
                changeSelectedMarker(markerHashMap)
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
            }

            setOnMarkerClickListener {
                handleOnMarkerClick(it)
                false
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what about disabling setOnMarkerClickListener does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

From [Official `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) for [`OnMarkerClick`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html#onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)):

> **Returns**
>
> - `true` if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur); false otherwise (i.e., the default
>     behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move
>     to the marker and an info window to appear.

So, for avoid default behavior for marker click (which is for the camera to move such that the marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one) your `public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)` should return `true`:

```
...
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // do what you need on marker ckick
        ...

        return true;  // <- this is the key
    }
});
...
```

or for your Kotlin code:

```
setOnMarkerClickListener {
    handleOnMarkerClick(it)
    true
}
```